# Object value not changing in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code :

```
 for (var item in oldMenu) {
   var newid = newID();
   oldMenu[item].nodeId = newid;
   db.selectDatas('pages','',{'datas.menu': item.nodeId},null,null,null,null, function(err1, page) {
     if(page.length > 0) {
       var oldPage = page[0].datas;
         oldPage.menu = newid;
       }
   });
```

#### Sample data of the oldMenu variable :

```
[
  {
    "nodeId": "e9c2b2a4-4583-eff9-d0de-bc4d7d2bf50f",
    "nodeText": "Présentation",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "count": 0,
    "expanded": true
  },
  {
    "nodeId": "be225e39-9848-913a-1b18-0f3995e2199a",
    "nodeText": "Installation",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "expanded": true
  },
  {
    "nodeId": "aa41e413-be60-460f-dbbe-84284245414b",
    "nodeText": "Premier lancement"
  }
]
```

The problem is that the items not changing `nodeId` field is not changing with the new value as expected, I'm missing something?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you provide sample data for oldMenu?

Comment: What happens if you replace `var` with `let` ?

Comment: @MattB I've added a sample data of the oldMenu variable

Comment: `for..in` is for iterating over object keys, not for arrays. Use `for..of` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `item.nodeId` in the `selectDatas` query when it should be `oldMenu[item].nodeId`. However you overwrite that value in the line above, so it will probably return 0 results.

Here's what I believe the code should be:

```
for (var item of oldMenu) {
   var oldId = item.nodeId;

   var newid = newID();
   item.nodeId = newid;

   db.selectDatas('pages','',{'datas.menu': oldId},null,null,null,null, function(err1, page) {
     if(page.length > 0) {
       var oldPage = page[0].datas;
         oldPage.menu = newid;
       }
   });
}
```